# How to pick up object based on pointer position and not player position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I found a code that works great in my game to pick up an object and throw it but when two objects are next to each other, the game picks both of them at the same time because it is calculated from player's distance to the object.

I tried to understand rays but I can't sort it out...

Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class ThrowObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public Transform playerCam;
    public float throwForce = 10;
    bool hasPlayer = false;
    bool beingCarried = false;

    public AudioClip[] soundToPlay;
    private AudioSource audio;
    public int dmg;
    private bool touched = false;


    void Start()
    {
        audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    void Update()
    {

        float dist = Vector3.Distance(gameObject.transform.position, Input.mousePosition);
        if (dist <= 2.5f)
        {
            hasPlayer = true;
        }
        else
        {
            hasPlayer = false;
        }       


        if (hasPlayer && Input.GetButtonDown("Use"))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
            transform.parent = playerCam;
            beingCarried = true;
        }
        if (beingCarried)
        {
            if (touched)
            {
                GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
                transform.parent = null;
                beingCarried = false;
                touched = false;
            }
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
                {
                    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
                    transform.parent = null;
                    beingCarried = false;
                    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(playerCam.forward * throwForce);
                RandomAudio();
                }
                else if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
                {
                GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
                    transform.parent = null;
                beingCarried = false;
                }
            }
        }
    void RandomAudio()
    {
        if (audio.isPlaying){
            return;
                }
        audio.clip = soundToPlay[Random.Range(0, soundToPlay.Length)];
        audio.Play();

    }
   void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        if (beingCarried)
        {
            touched = true;
        }
    }
    }
```

Any help would be gladly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay, out hitInfo)`

Comment: Hello, thank you for this, could you please give me more insights on how to integrate it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at OnMouseOver and OnMouseEnter functions
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseOver.html

Comment: Thank you very much for this, indeed, adding this:
void OnMouseOver()
    {
Changed and worked!